# How to prevent losing indentation when editing JavaScript code within HTML files in Emacs?

Tags: indentation, html, javascript

When I edit  JavaScript code which exists in an HTML file, I lose code indentation whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
first line of code:
    second line of code # Press Enter here
```

Result after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
first line of code
second line of code
```

(the indentation is lost)

How to prevent this?
P.S. I am using Emacs 25

Comment: In Markdown Mode, `RET` is already binding to `markdown-enter-key` by default. `C-h c RET` outputs `RET (translated from <return>) runs the command markdown-enter-key` from here.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to `electric-indent-mode`, which is a global minor mode.

You could add `(electric-indent-mode -1)` to your init file to disable it entirely, or you could try using a custom `electric-indent-functions` function.

The following is only minimally tested, but might do the trick:

```el
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my-html-mode-hook)

(defun my-html-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `html-mode' behaviours."
  (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions
            'my-html-mode-electric-indent-maybe nil :local))

(defun my-html-mode-electric-indent-maybe (_char)
  "Used in `electric-indent-functions'."
  (save-excursion
    (when (ignore-errors
            (string= (sgml-tag-name (sgml-parse-tag-backward))
                     "script"))
      'no-indent)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this bug is related to Emacs 25 because when I upgraded to version 25, I no longer am facing this problem.